# generating java objects with mws

Tags: java, jaxb, amazon-mws

I just started using the Amazon MWS (Marketing web services) and it seems that they no longer use wsdl
With the new amazon MWS that does not use soap how do I generate java objects with jaxb binding?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use [the Java Library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/feeds/v20090901/java.html/191-0032919-5984009) to solve your problems.